# Using password_hash with bindParam

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam

I'm trying to create a login system using Slim Jquery and Ajax. I've got the log in part working with minimal issues, now I just need to be able to hash the password. I know I can use md5, sha1 and/or salt to hash but I know that it is recommenced that password_hash is used instead. I know how to hash with any of the other 3 I mentioned because while using bindParam you can just place it around the variable. My question is, how do I use password_hash with bindParam. The closest answer I found on this site didn't do much to help.

My current code is:

```
$app->post('/addUser/', 'addUser');
function addUser()
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $q = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, userName, password) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :userName, :password)";

    try{
        $dbConnection();
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("firstName", $q->firstName);
        $stmt->bindParam("lastName", $q->lastName);
        $stmt->bindParam("userName", $q->userName);
        $stmt->bindParam("password", $q->password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db=null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Verify Code:

```
$app->post('/logIn/', 'lonIn');
function logIn()
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $q = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName=:userName";
    try{
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("userName", $q->userName);
        $execute = $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    if($execute == true)
    {
        $array = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $hashedPassword = $array['password'];
        if(password_verify($q->password), $hashedPassword))
        {
            echo 'Valid';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Invalid';
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there are different approach to this one you can choose to create a class to encode and decode passwords (best) you can also choose to create a simple function to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encrypt password you need to create a new variable $hashedPassword which you will store in the db for each user. When verifying the user you will select a user from the db passing their username and using password_verify($passToBeVerified,$ourHashedpasswordfromDb) this will return a boolean.

```
      $app->post('/addUser/', 'addUser');

function addUser() {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $q = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $hashedPassword = password_hash($q->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, userName, password) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :userName, :password)";

    try {
        $dbConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":firstName", $q->firstName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":lastName", $q->lastName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":userName", $q->userName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $hashedPassword);
        $execute = $stmt->execute();
        if ($execute == true) {
            $verifyUser = verifyUser($q->password, $q->userName);
            if ($verifyUser == TRUE) {
                echo 'valid Username and  Password';
            } else {
                echo 'Invalid Username and password';
            }
        }
        $db = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function verifyUser($passWordToVerify, $userNameToVerify) {
    // $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    //   $q = json_decode($request->getBody());
    //Select a user data according to their username
    $sql = "select firstName, lastName, userName, password from users where userName = :userName";
    try {
        $dbConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":userName", $userNameToVerify);
        $execute = $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    if ($execute == True) {
        /*
         * if the query executes and returs the user saved user details lets now compare
         * the password from the db and the password that the user has entered
         */
        $array = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $hashedPassword = $array['password'];
        if (password_verify($passWordToVerify, $hashedPassword)) {
            echo 'Password is valid!';
            return true;
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid password.';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this before. I must have not placed in the whole variable into the hash. I'll test this out now, thanks

Comment: @user3618687 try and then hit me up. I will sort you out :)

Comment: It didn't work. It stopped my php from working. Sorry it took so long for a reply, I was doing other things and almost forgot about replying.

Comment: @user3618687 which version of php are you developing on and what error are you getting.

Comment: @user3618687 you have an error cause the place holders for the bind param have syntax errors i have edited the answer. Add a full colon to have something like to all bind statements $stmt->bindParam(":firstName", $q->firstName);

Comment: I'm guessing it broke due to this `\Slim]Slim`, why did u do it?

Comment: @user3618687 i did a typo on the namespace for \Slim\Slim i have changed it i think everything should work now

Comment: @EternalHour :) my big hands can fit on the keyboard

Comment: Nah i made a mistake in the original post. But that wasn't the issue. When I tried a cUrl command on it it returned with a internal error

Comment: @user3618687 have changed the bindparam

Comment: It still shows as a Internal Server Error. I'll check what version of PHP I'm using a respond

Comment: @user3618687 password_hash,password_verfy,password_needs_rehash, password_info are available for Php 5.5  and later versions. Are you in a position to update your php

Comment: Yeah, no issues updating, i'll do it now and see if it works out. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @user3618687 your welcome. You can upvote the comments that have been helpful incase someone has the same issues ;)

Comment: I need rep of 15 or more but if this works I'll accept it as the correct answer

Comment: haha :) its ok still around you will find this place addictive and fun

Comment: Sorry about extremely long time before I could "Accept as answer" I haven't had time to try it out until just now. It works brilliantly, just 1 more question. How do I verify? I tried the same sort of layout '$verify = password_verify($q->password, password_hash($q->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));' and inputting $verify in the bindParams as well. The php runs no issue it just returns a false output instead of the database row like it should.

Comment: @user3618687 I will sort you out tomorrow am, am off to get some sleep. 

Comment: @user3618687 let me  edit my answer and add a verify function

Comment: So why can't you verify it during the original check?

Comment: What do you mean by during the original check

Comment: I mean within the try block, like it's done with the original hashing. Also I tried it out and it shot straight to the else statement. I'll edit my OP to contain my verify code atm

Comment: Its very possible you can call the verify function and pass the password and username as argument to this function after insert. But we cannot nest the insert and select statement. in the same prepare and execution. Having verify as a function make it possible to re use the function in your project.

Comment: @user3618687 a've my answer have a  look at it

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've got it working, using your verify solution with some edits.

Comment: @user3618687thats quite ok. Happy coding